# Best way to Populate a Column in R based on conditions related to other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a newbie in R, so I've solve my problem with a function and a for cycle, but based on what I've heard from R, it should be doable in a much cleaner and efficient way.

So I have a table, similar to this:

```
A,B,C
0.3,0.4,1
0.7,0.8,1
0.2,0.1,0
0.5,0.3,1
0.6,0.4,0
```

Where A is the probability method 1 gives me that an answer is 1,
B is the probability method 2 gives me that an answer is 1,
and C is the correct answer that the methods should have predicted. 
If the probability is above 0.5, then that's equivalent to the answer being a 1, otherwise, it's equivalent to the answer being a 0.

So, I want to create a column "D" that tells me if both methods got the right answer, if only one of the methods got the right answer, or if both were wrong. So that my final table would look like this:

```
A,B,C,D
0.3,0.4,1,BOTH_WRONG
0.7,0.8,1,BOTH_RIGHT
0.2,0.1,0,BOTH_RIGHT
0.5,0.3,1,ONLY_A
0.6,0.4,0,ONLY_B
```

So, I did this with a for cycle and a small function

```
compareAnswers <- function(a,b,c){
  if ( a == c & b == c ){
    res="BOTH_RIGHT"
  }
  else if ( a == c & b != c) {
    res="OnlyA"    
  }
  else if ( a != c & b == c) {
    res="OnlyB"    
  }
  else{
    res="BOTH_WRONG"
  }
  return(res)
}

df$A <- ifelse( df$A >= 0.5, 1, 0)
df$B  <- ifelse( df$B >= 0.5, 1, 0)

for( i in 1:nrow(df) ){
  df[i,]$D <- compareAnswers(
    df[i,]$A,
    df[i,]$B,
    df[i,]$C
  )
}
```

As I said, I just want to know if there's a better way to do this. thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(D = case_when(C == 1 & A >= 0.5 & B >= 0.5 ~ "BOTH_RIGHT",
                       C == 1 & A >= 0.5 ~ "ONLY_A",
                       C == 1 & B >= 0.5 ~ "ONLY_B",
                       C == 1 ~ "BOTH_WRONG",
                       C == 0 & A < 0.5 & B < 0.5 ~ "BOTH_RIGHT",
                       C == 0 & A < 0.5 ~ "ONLY_A",
                       C == 0 & B < 0.5 ~ "ONLY_B",
                       TRUE ~ "BOTH_WRONG"))

    A   B C          D
1 0.3 0.4 1 BOTH_WRONG
2 0.7 0.8 1 BOTH_RIGHT
3 0.2 0.1 0 BOTH_RIGHT
4 0.5 0.3 1     ONLY_A
5 0.6 0.4 0     ONLY_B
```

I think the advantage to this approach is that it's obvious to someone else who reads your code what you're doing.

---

Another much more compact approach is with a few mathematical operations:

```
Categories <- c("BOTH_WRONG","ONLY_A","ONLY_B","BOTH_RIGHT")
data$d <- with(data, Categories[1+(((A >= 0.5) == C) + ((B >= 0.5) == C) * 2)])
data
    A   B C          d
1 0.3 0.4 1 BOTH_WRONG
2 0.7 0.8 1 BOTH_RIGHT
3 0.2 0.1 0 BOTH_RIGHT
4 0.5 0.3 1     ONLY_A
5 0.6 0.4 0     ONLY_B
```

The second approach takes advantage of coercion of integer and logical vectors. `A >= 0.5` evaluates to `TRUE` for the first element. `C`'s first element is `1`, which coerces to `TRUE`. So `TRUE == TRUE` evaluates to `TRUE`.

We repeat this for `B`, and then and multiply the result by `2`. Then add the results for `A` and `B` together. If both are wrong, the result is `0`, if `A` is right `1`, if `B` is right `2` and both `3`. If we add `1` to this final result, we can then subset a character vector of result strings to get our desired output.

Comment: In your `dplyr` solution i thought about something like `round(A+.Machine$double.eps) == C & round(B+.Machine$double.eps) == C ~ "BOTH_RIGHT"` to break it down into four cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hey im also new with R and wanted to test my skills this is my take on a solution using an  "apply" function

```
#building dummy data
a <- sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
b <- sample(1:10,10,replace = T)
c <- sample(0:1,10,replace = T)
a <- a/10
b <- b/10
#write dummy data to dataframe "df"
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))

#function to create vector of output strings
populateData <- function(x) {
  out <- "BOTH_WRONG"
    if(round(x[1]+0.1) == x[3]){
      out <- "ONLY_A"    
    }
    if(round(x[2]+0.1) == x[3] & out == "ONLY_A"){
      out <- "BOTH_RIGHT"
    }
    if(round(x[2]+0.1) == x[3] & out == "BOTH_WRONG"){
      out <- "ONLY_B"
    }
  return(out)
}
#add column "d" to dataframe
df$d <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, populateData)
```

Outputs:

```
1.0,0.7,0,BOTH_WRONG
0.9,1.0,1,BOTH_RIGHT
1.0,0.1,1,ONLY_A
0.2,0.7,1,ONLY_B
1.0,0.6,1,BOTH_RIGHT
1.0,0.3,1,ONLY_A
0.4,0.2,0,BOTH_RIGHT
0.6,0.3,0,ONLY_B
0.8,0.3,0,ONLY_B
0.3,0.1,1,BOTH_WRONG
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with 2 logical comparisons. E.g.:

```
paste((dat$A >= 0.5) == as.logical(dat$C), (dat$B >= 0.5) == as.logical(dat$C))
#[1] "FALSE FALSE" "TRUE TRUE"   "TRUE TRUE"   "TRUE FALSE"  "FALSE TRUE"
```

If you need the labels as specified, then add them in as a `factor` variable:

```
factor(
  paste((dat$A >= 0.5) == as.logical(dat$C), (dat$B >= 0.5) == as.logical(dat$C)),
  levels = c("FALSE FALSE", "TRUE TRUE", "TRUE FALSE", "FALSE TRUE"),
  labels = c("both wrong", "both right", "only A", "only B")
)
#[1] both wrong both right both right only A     only B    
#Levels: both wrong both right only A only B
```